# Blat not recognised as command

Tags: c#, blat

I am having a very strange problem. I installed blat.exe by putting it in the `c:/windows/system32` folder and I can run it perfectly from the command line.

When I run it programatically from C# `Process.Start("cmd", "blat.exe blah blah")` it returns the error

> 'blat.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I also tried giving the full path but it will just reply

> c:/Windows/System32/blat.exe' is not recognized ...

Do you have any ideas / suggestions? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't ever be dumping random executables into windows system directories. I'm guessing that somewhere you're ending up running as a 32 bit process on a 64 bit machine and so hitting file system redirection.

Comment: Are you saying that `Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\blat.exe","args")` does _not_ work?

Comment: please dont write  `blah blah`. what if the problem is inside blah blah?

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing valid arguments to `cmd`. [Here's](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) some documentation.

Basically, if you want to start cmd with the argument that it should run blat.exe and then terminate, you will need to pass `/C "blat.exe blah blah"`. Like so:

```
Process.Start("cmd", "/C \"blat.exe blah blah\"")
```

However, as someone has already stated in the comments, you might as well just run blat.exe directly.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that Damien_The_Unbeliever was right. I simply moved blat from the windows directory to c:/blat/blat.exe and it works fine. For completeness and excuse me for the previous blah, blah, blah, the command that was failing is

```
        static void ExecuteCommandSync(object command)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
                new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(@"C:/Windows/System32/blat.exe", "-server 127.0.0.1:1099 -subject Hello -to myname@gmail.com -body theBody -p gmailsmtp -from myname@gmail.com");
            System.Diagnostics.Process process;
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(procStartInfo);
            process.WaitForExit();
            var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            var error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            var exitCode = process.ExitCode;
            Console.WriteLine(error);
            process.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception objException)
        {
            // to be logged
        }
    }
```

The variation with cmd.exe /c c:/Windows/System32/blat.exe was equally failing. Thanks very much for your help